# Source IO size "8" does not match sink IO size "4"

Tags: gnuradio

This is my first attempt at using GNU Radio.  I am trying to do [this](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Signal_Source) example, which is a sine wave generator.

The example works, so I am trying to connect the throttle block to the audio sink block.  I am getting an error that doesn't seem to match up with any of the options in the blocks.  The error is

```
   Source IO size "8" does not match sink IO size "4"
```

I googled around, but I didn't find anything related to the blocks I am using.  I also don't know what this error means, so I am hoping someone can match up the error to the parameters in the blocks.

Comment: The type of output doesn't match the type of input. So, what you're trying to do must be somewhat different to what's shown on that wiki page. I'd recommend you start with https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Tutorials instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Double click your "Signal Source" to open its property dialog
2. Change the "output type" from "complex" to "float"
3. Click "OK"

Now you should be good.